# Pandas Merge Error iterable, not itertools.imap

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to merge two dataframes using the pandas merge code below.  Each dataframe has just three columns.  I've done similar merges before without issue.  I've provided .info() on each dataframe.  I'm getting an error about iterable vs not itertools.imap.  I have no clue what they're talking about.  Any tips very much appreciated.

```
Data:

pio_smp2_sm.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 12779 entries, 15 to 68311
Data columns (total 3 columns):
entityId          12779 non-null object
targetEntityId    12779 non-null object
eventTime         12779 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 399.3+ KB


cm_smp2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 28035 entries, 40 to 698858
Data columns (total 3 columns):
user_id       28035 non-null object
product_id    28035 non-null object
time_stamp    28035 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 876.1+ KB


Code:

comp_df2=pd.merge(pio_smp2_sm,cm_smp2,how='inner',left_on=['entityId','targetEntityId'],right_on=['user_id','product_id'])


Error:

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-235-6882a22fe6a1> in <module>()
     23 
     24 
---> 25 comp_df2=pd.merge(pio_smp2_sm,cm_smp2,how='inner',left_on=['entityId','targetEntityId'],right_on=['user_id','product_id'])
     26 
     27 # print(comp_df2.shape[0])

/data2/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.pyc in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     56                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
     57                          validate=validate)
---> 58     return op.get_result()
     59 
     60 

/data2/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.pyc in get_result(self)
    580                 self.left, self.right)
    581 
--> 582         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    583 
    584         ldata, rdata = self.left._data, self.right._data

/data2/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.pyc in _get_join_info(self)
    746         else:
    747             (left_indexer,
--> 748              right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
    749 
    750             if self.right_index:

/data2/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.pyc in _get_join_indexers(self)
    725                                   self.right_join_keys,
    726                                   sort=self.sort,
--> 727                                   how=self.how)
    728 
    729     def _get_join_info(self):

/data2/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.pyc in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
   1048 
   1049     # get left & right join labels and num. of levels at each location
-> 1050     llab, rlab, shape = map(list, zip(* map(fkeys, left_keys, right_keys)))
   1051 
   1052     # get flat i8 keys from label lists

TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not itertools.imap
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `.head(10)` tells for both the dfs?

Comment: Do any of your key columns contain a list, or dict?

Comment: @ALollz Thanks, yeah the issue was in a previous step I ran .str.strip() on the user_id column and for some reason it turned every entry from 123 to [123].  Any idea why .str.strip() would do that?  I've never had it do that before.